How can i correctly use lambda function or CC_CALLBACK Macro for getting input from the user in cocos2d-x?
I am developing a game using cocos2d-x, in which i am trying to get input the path for the directory where i can save the game files. i have implemented it using UI Text Field and Menu Item but getting some weird error.
Here the code snippet for that:
std::string filePath = "";
auto textField = cocos2d::ui::TextField::create("Add Directory Path...", "Arial", 40);
if (textField) {
    textField->setPosition(cocos2d::Vec2((origin.x + visibleSize.width) / 2, (origin.y + visibleSize.height) * 0.70f));
    this->addChild(textField, 1);
}

auto enterButton = cocos2d::MenuItemImage::create("EnterButton.png", "EnterButtonHover.png", [&, textField](Ref* sender) {
    auto node = dynamic_cast<Node*>(sender);
    if (node != nullptr) {
        if (textField != nullptr) {
            filePath = textField->getString();
        }
    }
});

if (enterButton == nullptr || enterButton->getContentSize().width <= 0 || enterButton->getContentSize().height <= 0) {
    problemLoading("'EnterButton.png'");
}
else {
    enterButton->setPosition(cocos2d::Vec2((origin.x + visibleSize.width) / 2 + 350, (origin.y + visibleSize.height) * 0.70f));
}

auto menu = cocos2d::Menu::create(enterButton, NULL);
menu->setPosition(cocos2d::Vec2::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);

In this I have created the UI Text Field to allow user to enter the text and along with that i created the Menu Item (button) that user will press after completing its input. i want that when button is pressed then whatever is on the text field it get store in string variable filePath. but is throwing an exception. not in this chunk of code but inside the CCMenu.cpp, onTouchEnded function:
void Menu::onTouchEnded(Touch* /*touch*/, Event* /*event*/)
{
    CCASSERT(_state == Menu::State::TRACKING_TOUCH, "[Menu ccTouchEnded] -- invalid state");
    this->retain();
    if (_selectedItem)
    {
        _selectedItem->unselected();
        _selectedItem->activate(); //exception thrown here
    }
    _state = Menu::State::WAITING;
    _selectedWithCamera = nullptr;
    this->release();
}

Exception thrown at 0x6FEA757F (vcruntime140d.dll) in MyGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
To my understanding what this exception is about that program is trying to access the unallocated memory but i can't find out any violation in my program.
If anyone here, who come across any such situation or notice that i am doing anything wrong in the code, please suggest what can i do to solve this.

Run your program under a debugger and it will tell you exactly which variable is being accessed.

Where is filePath declared? Since it seems it's captured by reference you might have a dangling reference bug.

Finally solved the problem, i was using this code in member function and the filePath is also declared in it, that is causing the problem. by declaring filePath as a member variable the issue gets resolved :) .
